# Artefacts from Riemann sum in scipy.signal.convolve

Tags: python, scipy, convolution

**Short summary**: How do I quickly calculate the finite convolution of two arrays?

## Problem description

I am trying to obtain the finite convolution of two functions f(x), g(x) defined by

[image: finite convolution]

To achieve this, I have taken discrete samples of the functions and turned them into arrays of length `steps`:

```
xarray = [x * i / steps for i in range(steps)]
farray = [f(x) for x in xarray]
garray = [g(x) for x in xarray]
```

I then tried to calculate the convolution using the `scipy.signal.convolve` function. This function gives the same results as the algorithm `conv` suggested [here](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~masud/computing/WPark_recipes_in_python.html). However, the results differ considerably from analytical solutions. Modifying the algorithm `conv` to use the trapezoidal rule gives the desired results.

To illustrate this, I let

```
f(x) = exp(-x)
g(x) = 2 * exp(-2 * x)
```

the results are:

[image]

Here `Riemann` represents a simple Riemann sum, `trapezoidal` is a modified version of the Riemann algorithm to use the trapezoidal rule, `scipy.signal.convolve` is the scipy function and `analytical` is the analytical convolution.

Now let `g(x) = x^2 * exp(-x)` and the results become:

[image]

Here 'ratio' is the ratio of the values obtained from scipy to the analytical values. The above demonstrates that the problem cannot be solved by renormalising the integral.

## The question

Is it possible to use the speed of scipy but retain the better results of a trapezoidal rule or do I have to write a C extension to achieve the desired results?

## An example

Just copy and paste the code below to see the problem I am encountering. The two results can be brought to closer agreement by increasing the `steps` variable. I believe that the problem is due to artefacts from right hand Riemann sums because the integral is overestimated when it is increasing and approaches the analytical solution again as it is decreasing.

**EDIT**: I have now included the original algorithm [2](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~masud/computing/WPark_recipes_in_python.html) as a comparison which gives the same results as the `scipy.signal.convolve` function.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def convolveoriginal(x, y):
    '''
    The original algorithm from http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~masud/computing/WPark_recipes_in_python.html.
    '''
    P, Q, N = len(x), len(y), len(x) + len(y) - 1
    z = []
    for k in range(N):
        t, lower, upper = 0, max(0, k - (Q - 1)), min(P - 1, k)
        for i in range(lower, upper + 1):
            t = t + x[i] * y[k - i]
        z.append(t)
    return np.array(z) #Modified to include conversion to numpy array

def convolve(y1, y2, dx = None):
    '''
    Compute the finite convolution of two signals of equal length.
    @param y1: First signal.
    @param y2: Second signal.
    @param dx: [optional] Integration step width.
    @note: Based on the algorithm at http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~masud/computing/WPark_recipes_in_python.html.
    '''
    P = len(y1) #Determine the length of the signal
    z = [] #Create a list of convolution values
    for k in range(P):
        t = 0
        lower = max(0, k - (P - 1))
        upper = min(P - 1, k)
        for i in range(lower, upper):
            t += (y1[i] * y2[k - i] + y1[i + 1] * y2[k - (i + 1)]) / 2
        z.append(t)
    z = np.array(z) #Convert to a numpy array
    if dx != None: #Is a step width specified?
        z *= dx
    return z

steps = 50 #Number of integration steps
maxtime = 5 #Maximum time
dt = float(maxtime) / steps #Obtain the width of a time step
time = [dt * i for i in range (steps)] #Create an array of times
exp1 = [math.exp(-t) for t in time] #Create an array of function values
exp2 = [2 * math.exp(-2 * t) for t in time]
#Calculate the analytical expression
analytical = [2 * math.exp(-2 * t) * (-1 + math.exp(t)) for t in time]
#Calculate the trapezoidal convolution
trapezoidal = convolve(exp1, exp2, dt)
#Calculate the scipy convolution
sci = signal.convolve(exp1, exp2, mode = 'full')
#Slice the first half to obtain the causal convolution and multiply by dt
#to account for the step width
sci = sci[0:steps] * dt
#Calculate the convolution using the original Riemann sum algorithm
riemann = convolveoriginal(exp1, exp2)
riemann = riemann[0:steps] * dt

#Plot
plt.plot(time, analytical, label = 'analytical')
plt.plot(time, trapezoidal, 'o', label = 'trapezoidal')
plt.plot(time, riemann, 'o', label = 'Riemann')
plt.plot(time, sci, '.', label = 'scipy.signal.convolve')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: it might be helpful if you provide a [complete minimal example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the problem, to exclude trivial errors such as an integer division is used where true division must be used.

Comment: if you shift `sci` array to the right (by one step) and normalize it then the solutions [look similar](http://i403.photobucket.com/albums/pp111/uber_ulrich/convolve.png): [`sci = np.r_[0,sci[:steps-1]]*0.86`](https://gist.github.com/ac45fb5d117d8ecb66a3). It seems there are different definitions of what `convolve()` means (fft, circular), see discussion in [Convolution computations in Numpy/Scipy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6855169/4279).

Comment: Thank you for the references to the convolution thread. The right shift looks like an interesting way of fixing the problem. Can you tell me how you obtained the normalisation factor of 0.86?

I have included the original Riemann sum algorithm to illustrate why I believe this is a numerical artefact rather than a different definition of what convolution means.

Comment: the value `0.86`: `trapezoidal[1:]/sci[:-1]`. It shows only that the same constant factor works for all points.

Comment: Regarding the normalisation: Consider two different functions f(x)=exp(-x) and g(x)=x^2*exp(-x). Now the results cannot be mapped into each other using scalar multiplication. See example code here: https://gist.github.com/1626219 I have added a picture to the above post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**: Write it in C!

## Long answer

Using the cookbook about [numpy arrays](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/C_Extensions/NumPy_arrays) I rewrote the trapezoidal convolution method in C. In order to use the C code one requires three files (https://gist.github.com/1626919)

- The C code (performancemodule.c).
- The setup file to build the code and make it callable from python (performancemodulesetup.py).
- The python file that makes use of the C extension (performancetest.py)

The code should run upon downloading by doing the following

- Adjust the include path in `performancemodule.c`.
- Run the following

  python performancemodulesetup.py build
  python performancetest.py

You may have to copy the library file `performancemodule.so` or `performancemodule.dll` into the same directory as `performancetest.py`.

## Results and performance

The results agree neatly with one another as shown below:

[image: Comparison of methods]

The performance of the C method is even better than scipy's convolve method. Running 10k convolutions with array length 50 requires

```
convolve (seconds, microseconds) 81 349969
scipy.signal.convolve (seconds, microseconds) 1 962599
convolve in C (seconds, microseconds) 0 87024
```

Thus, the C implementation is about **1000 times** faster than the python implementation and a bit more than 20 times as fast as the scipy implementation (admittedly, the scipy implementation is more versatile).

**EDIT**: This does not solve the original question exactly but is sufficient for my purposes.

Comment: `Cython` allows you to create C extensions easily e.g., [`rotT()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4973390/4279).

Answer (score 1):

or, for those who prefer numpy to C. It will be slower than the C implementation, but it's just a few lines.

```
>>> t = np.linspace(0, maxtime-dt, 50)
>>> fx = np.exp(-np.array(t))
>>> gx = 2*np.exp(-2*np.array(t))
>>> analytical = 2 * np.exp(-2 * t) * (-1 + np.exp(t))
```

this looks like trapezoidal in this case (but I didn't check the math)

```
>>> s2a = signal.convolve(fx[1:], gx, 'full')*dt
>>> s2b = signal.convolve(fx, gx[1:], 'full')*dt
>>> s = (s2a+s2b)/2
>>> s[:10]
array([ 0.17235682,  0.29706872,  0.38433313,  0.44235042,  0.47770012,
        0.49564748,  0.50039326,  0.49527721,  0.48294359,  0.46547582])
>>> analytical[:10]
array([ 0.        ,  0.17221333,  0.29682141,  0.38401317,  0.44198216,
        0.47730244,  0.49523485,  0.49997668,  0.49486489,  0.48254154])
```

largest absolute error:

```
>>> np.max(np.abs(s[:len(analytical)-1] - analytical[1:]))
0.00041657780840698155
>>> np.argmax(np.abs(s[:len(analytical)-1] - analytical[1:]))
6
```