# fft numpy style on iOS accelerate with non power of two data length

Tags: ios, swift, numpy, fft, accelerate-framework

I'm working on reimplementing python code on iOS (swift).

I need to do an fft (numpy style) on chunks of 1D data. each with size 1050 (windowed audio data).

Thankfully I found related explanation and snippet of code on how to do iOS fft in numpy style ([link](https://github.com/jseales/numpy-style-fft-in-obj-c)).

However, I'm stuck where accelerate framework supports doing fft only on a [power of 2 input data length](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450150-vdsp_fft_zrip) (or [more recently](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450061-vdsp_dft_zop_createsetup),  f * 2^n, where f is 3, 5, or 15 and n is at least 3).

I tested my python code on window size 1050. Working great for my use case. But it is not straightforward to implement on iOS, because of the above limitation.

It is not so easy to dig into numpy c code to know how they're doing it for non power of two lengths. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841296/fft-in-numpy-python-when-n-is-not-a-power-of-2) was a good starting point for me, but still didn't get it.

Speed here is also important, that's why I'm not considering a brute force dft.

Any guidance here would be really appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean _numpy style_? As for data, Accelerate framework only supports data of 2^N length. There are some Swift frameworks for FFT, but many of them are based on Accelerate. You can try you luck with some C libraries - like [Fastest Fourier Transform in the West](http://www.fftw.org/download.html) which supports data of any length

Comment: I meant exactly how fft is implemented in numpy library in python. Different implementations of fft use different conventions, like zero-padding or some other tweaks, which depend sometimes on input data length.

Comment: Any implementation of FFT will yield the same result, regardless of algorithm used. FFT is deterministic, it is not an approximation of DFT - it **is** DFT, only calculated quicker. There is no point in insisting that it is calculated the same way as in numpy.

Comment: @mag_zbc Accelerate supports lengths of the form c*2^n, where c is 1, 3, 5, or 15 (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450061-vdsp_dft_zop_createsetup)

Comment: (but that's not going to help @msuliman much with 1050 = 2*3*5*5*7.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers/comments guided me to use c/c++ code to get the desired result. (I didn't think of that as an option initially).

I ended up using [opencv](https://opencv.org/) dft function (which internally implements fft) that produces similar results to numpy's fft (+ it is faster than numpy, according to their docs).

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, for fft, under-the-hood, numpy uses fftpack, a C conversion of an old NCAR Fortran math library. The actual numpy fft is not implemented in Python code.  You could very likely compile some fftpack C code using Xcode, and use a bridging header to call it from iOS Swift code.