# Why is the result in FFT code without using Scipy not similar to Scipy FFT?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, fft

The FFT code below did not give the result similar to `scipy` library of Python. But I don't know what's wrong in this code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from scipy.fftpack import fft

def omega(p, q):
   return np.exp((-2j * np.pi * p) / q)

def fft(x):
   N = len(x)
   if N <= 1: return x
   even = fft(x[0::2])
   odd = fft(x[1::2])
   combined = [0] * N
   for k in range(N//2):
     combined[k] = even[k] + omega(k,N) * odd[k]
     combined[k + N//2] = even[k] - omega(k,N) * odd[k]
   return combined

 N = 600
 T = 1.0 / 800.0
 x = np.linspace(0, N*T, N)
 #y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x) + 0.5*np.sin(80.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
 y = np.sin(50.0 * 2.0*np.pi*x)
 xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N//2)
 yf = fft(y)
 yfa = 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[0:N//2])
 plt.plot(xf, yfa)
 plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image: FFT plot]

Comment: You have implemented properly, but its not completely optimized. An FFT is basically the energy of a function. So you might get distortion of a little magnitude. If you want to see the actual implementation please refer to https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/fftpack/basic.py

Comment: Plot the scipy version. The differences should be fairly minimal. Depending on how you order and optimize the computation, roundoff error will creep in in different places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the above comments, *i.e.* roundoff errors and implementation correctness, are true but you missed an important thing... FFT Cooley and Tukey original algorithm is working only if the number of samples `N` is a power of 2. You did notice that

[image: N600]

```
np.allclose(yfa,yfa_sp)
>>> False
```

for your current input `N = 600`, the discrepancies are huge between your output and numpy/scipy. But now, let's use the closest power of two, in this case `N = 2**9 = 512`, which gives

```
np.allclose(yfa,yfa_sp)
>>> True
```

Wonderful! Outputs are now identical this time, and it can be verified for other powers of 2 (Nyquist criterion apart) sizes of input signal `y`.  For in depth explanations, you may read accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841296/fft-in-numpy-python-when-n-is-not-a-power-of-2) to understand why numpy/scipy fft functions may allow all `N` (with most efficiency when `N` is a power of two, and least efficiency when `N` is prime) instead of just handling this error as you should have, with something like:

```
if np.log2(N) % 1 > 0:
    raise ValueError('size of input y must be a power of 2')
```

or even, using bitwise `and` operator (a truly elegant test imo):

```
if N & N-1:
    raise ValueError('size of input y must be a power of 2')
```

As suggested in the comments, if size of the signal could't be modified so easily, zero-padding is definitely the way to go for this kind of sampling issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Yacoba: oh, thank you very much for your detail explanation. It is very useful to me.

Comment: ...and if your signal is not the right length you can simply append zeros until it's a power of two: zero padding in one domain results in sinc interpolation in the dual domain.